# displaying an image from Firebase storage using next/image results in a 400 status code

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am using the NextJS Image component like this:

```
import Image from "next/image";
<Image src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dzgamez.appspot.com/o/images%2Fsecondary_1629980734220.png?alt=media"
          alt="Top Banner"
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
          className="rounded-sm"
        />
```

but the image is not displayed ,I've tried the same link in img tag and it work fine, and when I add the unoptimized={true} prop it work but not optimazed

can any one help me fix this problem please , you can use the firebase link above